# Where are the bind and identity functions on the Nullable<T> monad?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, programming-languages, monads, category-theory

My understanding of monads is still being formed. I understand that aside from being associative, the other three contracts that a monad has to adhere to are `identity`, `pure` and `bind`.

I infer that the constructor of `Nullable<T>` forms the pure function, I do not see any `identity` and `bind` functions on `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Monads are usually defined using functions called `return` and `bind`, where did you hear about `identity` and `pure`?

Comment: @svick I have watched many videos now all of which offer a different lexicon, but the same concepts. What I am calling `pure` is definitely the `return` function you mention. I am wondering where the `bind` is, and since I asked the question, I have been thinking more about `Nullable<T>` implementation and monads that I am suspecting that there doesn't need to be a method that does the binding but just that the object must allow for binding. I am wondering what mechanism in `Nullable<T>` allows for binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net does not contain the `bind` method for `Nullable<T>`, but it gives you enough to build one yourself:

```
static Nullable<T2> Bind<T1, T2>(Nullable<T1> source, Func<T1, Nullable<T2>> f)
    where T1 : struct where T2 : struct
{
    return source.HasValue ? f(source.Value) : null;
}
```

C# does contain something similar (but less general) than `bind`: the null conditional operator `?.`. Assuming `a` is of type `Nullable<T1>` and `B` is a property of type `Nullable<T2>`, then `a?.B` is equivalent to `Bind(a, x => x.B)`.

Comment: Then it is correct to think that sparing `IEnumerable<T>` and its derivatives or duals, namely `IObservable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>` and `IQbservable<T>`, there are no monads in the CLR type system that satisfy all the properties of a monad? I also observe that `IEnumerable<T>` does not have `identity` or `return` (it does have `Empty` and `Range` but no `return`) while `IObservable<T>` does have `Return` and one of its internal classes has an `Omega` which returns the last element of a single element sequence as itself.

Comment: Oh wait! `Enumerable` does have `AsEnumerable` on the non-generic `IEnumerable`. But still, that's not `return`, which is supposed to take a `T` and return an `M<T>`. And there is no `identity` functor either..

Comment: `IEnumerable`'s 'unit' is `x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1)`. Yes, that's a slightly roundabout way to put it, but here too, one's free to add their own extension method.